# Regex help - trying to detect a string or a regular expression - c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have input that comes in a comma delimited list of strings that may represent normal strings or regular expression encapsulated in double quotes.

> "[A-Z][0-9]", Hello

or

> "[A-Z][0-9]", "[A-Z][0-9]"

or

> Hello, Hello

So basically the regex can have a normal string on either side of the comma or string on either side of the comma of a regular expression encapusalted by double quotes. There could be any number of these lines seperated by new lines that will be parsed through one at a time. I was trying to do a combination of regular expressions to match anything inside of a double quote as well as combining it with string split to get the comma delimiter.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach line.. ..{
    dic.Add(line Split('\n')
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])); 
}
```

So i had figured that this solves the splitting on comma and new lines and puts the left side and right side it its propper key value spot in the dictionary. The problem here is that regular expressions may contain a comma. or new line which messes up the split. That is why I figured I need to also try and match what is in the  double quotes directly. Any help on the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

`(?<val1>".*"|(?:[^,]+)),(?<val2>(?:".*")|(?:[^,]+))`

The 2 values will be in capture groups `val1` and `val2`

https://regex101.com/r/oL6mQ1/2

The regular expression can be used to process the lines like so:

```
  var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  var re = new Regex("(?<val1>\".*\"|(?:[^,]+)),(?<val2>(?:\".*\")|(?:[^,]+))", 
                     RegexOptions.Compiled);

  var match = re.Match(line);
  var val1 = match.Result("${val1}");
  var val2 = match.Result("${val2}");
  dic[val1] = val2;
```

Comment: Where is <val1> and <val2> set? Can I combine this somehow in the line .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]) ?

Comment: Using `".*"` to parse string literal is very flaky. In general, this problem should be resolve with CSV parser.

Comment: See update answer with C# code to extract val1 and val2 using the regex

Comment: @nhahtdh It is not 'flaky' if the format as stated is adhered to. CSV parsers have issues of their own.